# Can I bring protein powder and health bars into the UK from the US?

Tags: health, uk, customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, airports

Will be travelling to the U.K. from the U.S. and would like to take my protein powder and some health bars to snack on during my visit.  Is this allowed to bring into the country?

Comment: Just curious - you can buy those fairly easily in the UK - any reason you particularly want to bring your own?

Comment: http://www.defra.gov.uk/food-farm/food/personal-imports/rules/

Answer (score 5):

This is an old thread, but just to close the loop, it is my understanding that dairy (even if powder) products are not allowed unless you carry a health certificate with them.

Thus any milk-based protein powder will face an issue.

Comment: This is exactly correct. The [UK government website](http://www.defra.gov.uk/food-farm/food/personal-imports/rules/) cited in Brian Nixon's comment below the question continues to state that one may not bring "milk or milk-based products, except powdered infant milk, infant food or special food (including pet food) needed for medical reasons" from the US.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason why not, unless your planning to import enough to pass from personal to commercial use. In my experience, custom agents are mostly interested in  animal or plant products and not packaged foods.

Comment: This is not correct. See the answer above from John Connor and comment below.